# Java : LibGDX AppHangB1 error

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I am developing a game using Java - LibGDX framework , Box2D physics engine . And when I play my game from several time I get this error, the game crashes . What can cause this error?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the application was hanging and not responding to windows queries if its active. Usually this gets caused by a very long loop that hogs all the cpu. If you use threads, give your threads some pause in between processing stuff.

Make the run function call return often enough so space is left to handle other application calls.

Also, keep processing and rendering thread seperated if you haven't done that already.

Monitor your game ticks, see what causes the overhead.

Try to limit your game ticks. 20-30 game ticks per second is usually more than enough for game updates.

Without any code, or stacktraces it's really really hard to tell what's going wrong.

Comment: so it can be for example from infinite loop?

Comment: A game is an infinite loop per definition. It runs till the loop quits. The important part is to have gameloop and render thread seperated. The game loop should calculate mobs, players updates in 20-30 ticks a second. Render yhread should only read variables not calculate them. Its not for a render thread to calculate health or hitboxes. The main gui/window eventhandlers should be in main thread. The main thread should start up the game, network and render threads. That way the main app thread can handle OS queries.

Comment: Always happy to help. Just keep an eye an your thread synchronisation. Use packets of data for network threads that you can simply pass around and just read data from but not write once its sent.  The render thread should only read and not write. The main game thread receives input and network packet data and does stuff with that. Your main game loop should have a pause after the tick is done calculating. Giving the garbage collector time to clean up. For example if you do 20 ticks per second like mc a tick should ideally finish in 10ms and not hog the full 50ms